# How to remove object from local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

This is my code i want to remove https://prnt.sc/j9Un7C5nxDCZ custom pack 1 object from localstorage i tried removeitem()  but its not deleting my object

```js
var all_pack = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CartItems"));

var object_length = Object.keys(all_pack).length;

var selected_option = "custom meal pack-1";

for (var i = 0; i < object_length; i++) {
  var p = Object.keys(all_pack)[i];
  if (selected_option === p) {
    Object.keys(all_pack)[i].removeItem();
  }
}
```

Comment: [`removeItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) is a method of [`Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage). You can't call it on a string. A storage stores strings. You have to read the string, parse it, modify it, serialize it and write it back. It seems like you don't want `removeItem`, but [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A storage stores strings. You have to read the string, parse it, modify it, serialize it and write it back.

Your code snippet lets me assume, that you don't want to remove an item from storage, but to delete a property from an object, that is stored in the local storage.

```
const all_pack = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CartItems"));

const selected_option = "custom meal pack-1";

for (key in all_pack) {
  if (selected_option === key) {
    delete all_pack[key];
  }
}

// update local storage
// localStorage.setItem("CartItems", JSON.stringify(all_pack));
```

Example:

```js
const all_pack = JSON.parse('{ "custom meal pack-1": true, "custom meal pack-2": true}');
    
const selected_option = "custom meal pack-1";
    
for (key in all_pack) {
  if (selected_option === key) {
    delete all_pack[key];
  }
}

console.log(all_pack);
```

Comment: So you miss the localStorage opdate

Comment: @mplungjan There is no localStorage update in the code in the question. It's unclear whether the update is expected. I added an optional line in a comment.

Comment: It was already unclear, but your suggestion did seem to need a save after deleting